# scrape text by HTML class using BeautifulSoup return null

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the comments information from this page([http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Java-Patrick-Niemeyer/dp/1449319246%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAIZJQKUHUCXRLH6MQ%26tag%3Dyuplayit-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D1449319246](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449319246)), the text inside the tag`<div class=“drkgry”>....</div>`but it always shows returns `[]`. I don’t know what’s happening.

python:

```
import bs4 from BeautifulSoup
data = open("example_1.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
soup.find_all("div",class="drkgry")
```

I’ve also tried `soup.findall("div",class="drkgry"), soup.find_all('div', attrs ={'class':'drkgry'}),`but they just doesn't work.

The data source I want to scrape:

```
</div>  <div class="txtsmall mt4 fvavp"><span class="inlineblock formatVariation"><span class="gr3 gry formatKey">Format:</span><span class="formatValue">Paperback</span></span></div>  <div class="mt9 reviewText">






<div class="drkgry">
  Learning Java (Fourth Edition) is book for Java practitioner as reference book. This covers lot of topics.<br><br>This is an excellent book for someone who knows basics of programming. This book is not beginners. This book lacks examples and exercises which may disappoint few people.<br><br>Book has 24 chapters covering almost all of basic Java.  The chapter one talks about historical aspects. Second chapter is brief introduction of java but it assumes that reader is aware of programming, OOP, threading etc which is difficult for any beginner.
</div>

</div>  <div class="clearboth txtsmall gt9 vtStripe">    <div class="fl cmt">
```

Does anyone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

i  ran this exact script:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html =urllib.urlopen('http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449319246/?tag=stackoverfl08-20').read()

soup = BS(html)

print soup.findAll('div',{'class':'drkgry'})[1].get_text()
```

and it printed:

> Learning Java (Fourth Edition) is book for Java practitioner as reference book. This covers lot of topics.This is an excellent book for someone who knows basics of programming. This book is not beginners. This book lacks examples and exercises which may disappoint few people.Book has 24 chapters covering almost all of basic Java.  The chapter one talks about historical aspects. Second chapter is brief introduction of java but it assumes that reader is aware of programming, OOP, threading etc which is difficult for any beginner.

if you run it without indexing the `soup.findAll` then it gives you a list of all the information in the comments

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. My error for the answer is "list index out of range?"

Comment: ok take the `[1].get_text()` off the end and tell me what it prints

Comment: Are you putting the .py file in BeaitifulSoup directory?

Comment: Do you downlaod the html file in your local computer ?

Comment: no, I ran the script from my Python directory and it works fine

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it is a BeautifulSoup version issue.n

Comment: Yeah it could have to do with youre beautiful soup make sure its returning all the HTML from the page

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
class_="drkgry"
```

Instead of:

```
class = "drkgry"
```

That's all, i think.